# DataTables warning: table id=incomeDataTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatable

I am bit new in ASP .Net MVC and still on learning mode. I am getting this error after leaving the controller. Tried to find the solution on this forum but unfortunately none of them are helping.
My Code is as under:

**Model:**

```
namespace TestHRMS3SIS.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class T11922H01
    {
        public int PMITHUniqueId { get; set; }
        public string PMITHIncomeId { get; set; }
        public string PMITHIncomeIdK { get; set; }
        public string PMITHDesc1 { get; set; }
        public string PMITHDesc2 { get; set; }
        public bool PMITHIsTaxable { get; set; }
        public string PMITHRuleId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PMITHRentExemptPercent { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PMITHRentCityPercent { get; set; }
        public string PMITHIncomeCycle { get; set; }
        public byte PMITHPrintingSeq { get; set; }
        public string PMITHRoundingStrategy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PMITHBICode { get; set; }
        public string PMITHBIDesc { get; set; }
        public int PMITHMarkForDeletion { get; set; }
        public string PMITHUser { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime PMITHDateTime { get; set; }
    
        public virtual T11922F01 T11922F01 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Income List";
}

<h2>Income List New</h2>

<table id="incomeDataTable">
    <thead>enter code here
        <tr>
            <th>IncomeId</th>
            <th>Dsc1</th>
            <th>Desc2</th>
            <th>RuleId</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section scripts
{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#incomeDataTable").DataTable(
                {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/DataTableTest/GetIncomeList",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "PMITHIncomeId" },
                        { "data": "PMITHDesc1" },
                        { "data": "PMITHDesc2" },
                        { "data": "PMITHRuleId" }
                    ]
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestHRMS3SIS.Models;

namespace TestHRMS3SIS.Controllers.DataTableTest
{
    public class DataTableTestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: DataTable
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetIncomeList()
        {
            using (Entities3SIS oDbConnection = new Entities3SIS())
            {
                var oT11922H01 = oDbConnection.T11922H01.ToList<T11922H01>();
                return Json(new { data = oT11922H01 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have put a break point in controller and observed that on return statement I am getting this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the columns section like below:

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "pmithIncomeId" },
    { "data": "pmithDesc1" },
    { "data": "pmithDesc2" },
    { "data": "pmithRuleId" }
]
```

The return data is camelCase.

Comment: Thanks mj.
This is not helping. First 5 letters in the above fields are prefix of each field in the SQL table. I tried changing to your suggestion. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi @ShishirDonde, please debug this method `GetIncomeList`, seem it has some error.

Comment: No it is not having any error. I am able to reach up to return statement with a list of 12 rows in variable oT11922H01.
After pressing F10 on 
return Json(new { data = oT11922H01 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  I am getting this error.

Comment: @ShishirDonde, you can use some tools like postman, or just enter the url (.../DataTableTest/GetIncomeList)  in the browser to test this method,  check if it return the right data.